# Problem with wkhtmltopdf in docker container

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm building a web app with flask, I'm trying to export a html to a pdf file.

```
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=my_path_to_wkhtmltopdf_exe)
options = {
    "disable-local-file-access": "",
    "enable-local-file-access": None
}

html = render_template(<my_html_flie>)

pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, configuration=config, options=options)
response = make_response(pdf)
```

The problem I have is that the code runs perfectly fine on local development. I already install the wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, and xvfb on the docker image. So I doubt it's about any dependencies issue. when I deploy it to docker container it no longer works and it's gonna throw me a few errors below

raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr))
OSError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/application/nog/men/routes.py", line 65, in view_b
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, configuration=config, options=options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfkit/api.py", line 72, in from_string
return r.to_pdf(output_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfkit/pdfkit.py", line 159, in to_pdf
raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr))
OSError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
```

The line

```
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, configuration=config, options=options)
```

is highlighted and I suspect that the error is coming from this line, can anyone give me advice on what might be wrong?

And this is my Dockfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

WORKDIR /application
COPY . .

RUN apk update \
  && apk add gcc libc-dev g++ \
  && apk add unixodbc-dev \
  && apk add gfortran \
  && apk add unixodbc

RUN apk add linux-headers
RUN apk add libffi-dev
RUN apk add openssl-dev
RUN apk add mysql-dev
RUN apk add openssl-dev

RUN apk add xvfb
RUN apk add --no-cache wkhtmltopdf

RUN apk add freetds freetds-dev
RUN pip install pymssql

RUN python3 -m pip install pyodbc
#RUN pip install apache-airflow[pymssql]


RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps build-base linux-headers \
    && pip install Pillow

RUN export DISPLAY=:1


RUN pip install -r requirments.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["run.py"]
```

Comment: Please, add your Dockerfile content to the post.

Comment: @jgtvares Yup, I just add my dockerfile content, thanks for the advice

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this myself, but this [issue](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/issues/106) could help you out

Comment: Also, you have way too many `RUN`'s in your Dockerfile. You can install the system's dependencies in a single command, for example: `apk add gcc libc-dev unixodbc-dev gfortran ...`, same goes for the Python installations. Too many `RUN` commands create too many layers in your image, it can be bad for your build performance and make your image heavier in disk space. So it's always nice to remove unnecessary commands.

Comment: Also, I'm almost certain that this code `RUN export DISPLAY=:1` won't work.
The `export` command adds an environment variable in the current shell. When this layer is executed, the shell dies, so the variable won't exist when the container is up. To export a global variable you need to use `ENV`. In your case would be something like: `ENV DISPLAY=:1`